# Proving that residuals from logistic regression are orthogonal to the predictions

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, residuals, predictor

I am stuck on proving that residuals from logistic regression are orthogonal to the predictions.

However, I am able to prove that residuals are orthogonal to the predictors since  score vector ( vector of first derivatives of the log-likelihood with respect to the parameter $\beta$) is

$\nabla_\beta l(\beta;y,X)= \sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i-g(x_i\beta ))x_i$, where $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

and $\hat{\beta}=\underset{\beta}{\operatorname{argmax}}l(\beta;y,X)$ (i.e. it is the value that $\nabla_\beta l(\hat{\beta};y,X) = 0$).

Any advice on how I can proceed?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "predictions"?  The $x_i\beta$ or the $g(x_i\beta)$?  In either case, why would one even expect (a) the orthogonality to hold and (b) have any use or meaning?  The issue here is that orthogonality ultimately is related to $L^2$ (least squares) losses, but the usual sense of "logistic regression" does not consider $L^2$ losses--it is based on maximizing the likelihood.

Comment: I totally agree with you, it hasn't any sense but it is an exercise from an assignment. I think the teacher refers to $g(x_i\beta)$ as predictions. I have already searched in several books without any success.

Comment: Note that for a Gaussian response variable, maximizing the likelihood is equivalent to $L^2$ loss minimization. Alas, logistic regression has a binomial response variable, not Gaussian.

Comment: The problem is that what you were asked to prove isn't true.  The shortest counterexample is the $(x,y)$ dataset $(0,0),$ $(1,1),$ $(2,1).$

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, this is false, and I constructed a counterexample via simulation.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 100                           # Sample size
x <- runif(N, -2, 2)               # predictor
z <- x                             # Linear combination of predictors
pr <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))              # "True" conditional probability
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr)              # response
L <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial) # Logistic regression
preds <- 1/(1 + exp(-predict(L)))  # predictions
resids <- y - preds                # residuals
sum(preds * resids)                # inner product
```

I get the inner product of the predictions and residuals of $0.238$, meaning that the predictions and residuals are not orthogonal.

Given that the link function makes a logistic regression nonlinear, this is not surprising.

Comment: If you change the regression to a linear regression via `L <- lm(y ~ x)` and `preds <- predict(L)`, the inner product is on the order of $10^{-14} = 0.00000000000001$, within what I would expect from doing arithmetic on a computer.